# Looking for help in data validation

Tags: excel, vba

I have data validation cells in two sheets. Im looking for a code if I change the value of data validation in sheet A, then Sheet B's data validation should be selected with same value. In same way if I select a value in Sheet B, then Sheet A's value should be selected automatically to same value.

Comment: What kind of validation! Are you talking about a `List` validation type? If so, do both of them use the same list? And you want the selected value in first sheet Drop-down cell to be also filled in the second sheet? In which ranges/cells of the two sheets does the validation exist? If not, what kind of validation are you talking about?

Comment: It is a list validation, but again each validation has been linked to other tables.

Comment: What "again" should mean in this context? Do you suggest that is it mentioned in your question? Then, what do you mean by "each validation has been linked to other tables"? Do you mean that the list used for validation is based on a table row/column, for each? If so, are the linked ranges identic? If not so, what else do you mean?

Comment: Again - I meant that the validation cell is connected to other table data...I didnt mention in my question, about the connection.

Comment: This is irrelevant... **are the linked ranges identic?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try using the next way. In the both sheets `Worksheet_Change` event you should copy the next code, and **correctly fill the other sheet name and validated cells correct addresses**:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim thisShAddress As String, secShAddress As String, secSh As Worksheet
   Const secondShName As String = "Sheet152" 'use here the name of THE OTHER sheet
   thisShAddress = "B1": secShAddress = "B1" 'use here the correct cells addres, even if they are not in the same place
   
   Set secSh = Worksheets(secondShName)
   If Target.cells.count <> 1 Then Exit Sub
   If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range(thisShAddress)) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False 'to avoid triggering the event when the change is done and start an infinite loop...
         secSh.Range(secShAddress).Value = Target.Value
        Application.EnableEvents = True
   End If
End Sub
```

It assumes that you only select a Data Validation option and not paste something over the cell.

Please, send some feedback after testing them, or ask for clarifications if something is not clear...

Comment: Thankyou for taking time and sharing the code, I will try and get back to you

Comment: The above code is not working, I have update the address, secondsheet name, but whenever I change the data validation list value. It is doing nothing

Comment: @Nishanth Sappidi Did you copy the above code **twice**? In the both involved sheets **code module**. And adapt it for each sheet, as suggested. `secondShName ` is different , it should be **the other sheet name**... If you did that, do you have TeamViewer or AnyDesk installed? If so, may I connect to your computer to see what's happening?

Comment: I copied the code twice, I changed the Seconshname accordingly ...If the code is in first sheet I update secondsheet name value for secondShName vice versa

Comment: @Nishanth Sappidi And did you update the cells address where the validated cells to trigger the event exist? You did not say anything about TeamViewer or AnyDesk...

Comment: Sheet1s cell address is D18, so I updated D18 and for sheet D19 so I have updated accordingly

Comment: @Nishanth Sappidi Please, check if events are enabled: `Debug.print Application.EnableEvents`. What does it return in `Immediate Window`? Then, place a breakPoint on the line `If Target.cells.count <> 1 Then Exit Sub` and change something in the respective sheet. Does the code stop on that line?

Comment: Sorry one of my relative passed away and I couldnt respond to the above. When I used Debug.print Application.EnableEvents it shows true

Comment: @Nishanth Sappidi But, what did you wrongly configured, if events were enabled?

Comment: @Nishanth Sappidi I would also like to remind you that we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the provided solution works...

Comment: I ticked it now, thank you for all the help

Comment: I have one question, I have written a code when opt1 button selected op2button needs to false, opt3 needs to be true and opt4 needs to be false...It is working exactly same way but it is not highlighting the opt3 button as selected, Can you please help

Comment: @Nishanth Sappidi Firstly, option buttons are not very suitable for such a use. I mean, their main characteristic is: **when one of them is checked, ALL the others automatically are unchecked**. Of course, if they are in the same group. This means `Option`...   I think, check  boxes will be more suitable with the job you try giving to them. Then, what kind of Option buttons are you talking about? Are they on a sheet or on a form? Are they ActiveX of Form controls? I mean, do they expose the `Change` event? Without seeing the code you are using, nobody can help you with an useful advice...

Comment: option 1 & 2 are in one sheet , opt 3 & 4 in second sheet. these are activex control buttons

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248732/discussion-between-nishusruj-and-faneduru).